# One event handler negates another in jquery -- click()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having an issue where when one click() handler is called then the other click() handler on a different element won't be called again.

Basic HTML Elements

```
<label for="pix_size">Default Pixel Size:</label><br>
<input id="pix_size">
<button id="action">Action</button>
<div id="here_table"></div>
```

Then there is some jquery code to create a table, add classes to the columns, etc. I didn't include here because I wanted to keep it succinct.

Here are the event handlers that appear to be in conflict

```
$("tr.remRow").click(function() {    // do something when a specific row was clicked
   alert(($(this).index() + 1) + " row was clicked" + 
         "and its rem value is " + $(this).children(".remColumn").text()); 
});

$("#action").click(function () {    // button event handler
    curPixSize = $("#pix_size").val(); // this refers to the 2nd row in the table
    redrawTable(3,5, curPixSize); // redraw the table with the new value from the input
});
```

the tr.remRow works great until I click the button, then it will never be called again. I am sure I just don't understand some jquery binding mechanism but a point in the right direction would be great. I want users to be able to click the button, focus/blur the input element, etc and then still be able to click on a row in the table.

Comment: its cause its dynamically added. need to use jquery "on".

Comment: "redraw the table" <- does that mean insert the table dynamically, replacing the current table? If so you need delegated event handlers.

Comment: almost seems like you need `$("#here_table").on('click',"tr.remRow",function() {` - hard to tell without markup, but if that div hold the "created by script code" table that would make it work/better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF this is your markup:

```
<label for="pix_size">Default Pixel Size:</label><br>
<input id="pix_size">
<button id="action">Action</button>
<div id="here_table"><table>
rest of table here
</table></div>
```

and you have code that replaces that table, then this would make it work:

```
$("#here_table").on('click',"tr.remRow",function() { 
   alert(($(this).index() + 1) + " row was clicked" + 
         "and its rem value is " + $(this).children(".remColumn").text()); 
});
// no change here:
$("#action").click(function () {  
    curPixSize = $("#pix_size").val();
    redrawTable(3,5, curPixSize);
});
```

Comment: That did it, thank you! Have some learning to do on delegates but that worked like a charm. Thank you all as I was led by everyone to delegates.

Comment: This is sort of the same idea, but it hooks the event handler to the `$('#here_table')` element - basically, you want to use the `.on()` with the closest parent ("here_table" div in this case) that will NOT be replaced/removed etc., then target the action of the event within that parent - the table row with that class in this case.  Otherwise, if the element gets removed (the table) the event handler    hook will get removed with the element.  Worst case you can hook to `$(document)` but I would advise against that due to the need to traverse everything looking for the target element (the tr)

Comment: Great, thank you! My main open question I am still researching is how to perform an different operation upon click for different child elements of the table DIV? In other words, do one thing for the THead row and another for the TBODY rows, or does that require tow different delegate statements?

Comment: What you describe is a different click handler, or (not as easy) add multiple targets in the list with the `tr` and then detect which one in the body of the handler - I would let separate handlers do the work if I were doing it since you indicate they will do different things.

Answer (score 0):

try using something like

```
$('table').on('click', 'tr.remRow', funciton () {
alert(($(this).index() + 1) + " row was clicked" + 
         "and its rem value is " + $(this).children(".remColumn").text());
}
```

Comment: Tried this and still same functionality, doing some more research on delegated event handlers.

Comment: then do it on the parent or even the document - events bubble

Answer (score 0):

add delegate to the first parent element that is not redrawn. in this case, i guess that is here_table element.